# Space at the end of title attribute in 'a' tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link like this:

```
<a title="Lorem ipsum " href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

Important is the space at the end of title attribute. If this link comes to the browser, it will change to this:

```
<a title="Lorem ipsum " &nbsp;href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

This is not valid link so it do not work. It is not a JavaScript problem, it is not working in Firefox 44.0.2 and Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit). W3C validator throws an error saying that "Attribute  href not allowed on element a at this point.". Why is a space at the end of title attribute a problem? It was working a while ago.

Comment: What changes it to @nbsp; ? How is it being generated and sent to the browser?

Comment: What do you mean "If this link comes to the browser"?

Comment: I strongly suspect there is something else going on here. I've never seen any issue like this. You'll probably need to provide more information.

Comment: If i send HTML with this broken link to the browser it do not work. If you open inspector over the broken link and you will edit it as HTML then you will see nbsp entity.

You can view it here:
http://www.novinky.cz/zahranicni/evropa/394952-vlada-na-ukrajine-ma-namale-porosenko-vyzval-premiera-jacenuka-aby-odstoupil.html

Last paragraph, link in [celá zpráva]

Comment: What language are you using to generate the html?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.novinky.cz%2Fzahranicni%2Fevropa%2F394952-vlada-na-ukrajine-ma-namale-porosenko-vyzval-premiera-jacenuka-aby-odstoupil.html

Comment: It is generated with Python.

Answer (score 0):

This `<a title="Lorem ipsum " href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum</a>` works fine for me. 
I wouldnt say it was JS, or anything like that, you may want to check the surroundings tags (div/h1,h2,p etc), make sure they are all correct. This is the only thing it could be.

Try placing `<a title="Lorem ipsum " href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum</a>` in a html document on its own and seeing what the inspect comes back as, as it was fine for me.

Hope this helps.